# Android device: unfortunately, appium settings has stopped

Tags: android, appium

trying to launch app on Android device and I keep seeing

```
Unfortunately, Appium
Settings has stopped. OK
```

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes up when you have an Older version of the "Appium Settings" App

Goto Application manager, Appium Settings.

My version was 1.0. Force Stop, Unistall
Next time you run Appium against the device the current version of Appium Settings will be downloaded - 2.3 (1/25/18)

Answer (score 0):

This comes up when you have an Older version of the "Appium Settings" App

Goto Setting > Application manager > Appium Settings > uninstall the app

Now your next run Appium setting version get installed with latest.
my case(2.3v)

That's it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue.

```
Appium V. - 1.7.2
Device: Nexus 7
Android: 6.0.1
```

I also tried after manually uninstalling both appium apks. But issue not resolved.

Same issue doesn't occur where `Android v. is 5.1.1.`

Answer (score 0):

@mancocapac , You are right. But in my case I followed the step which you are asking for.

```
Forced stop "Appium Setting" App.
Uninstalled it.
Re-executed.
```

But still, issue was replicating.

Then I did the factory reset to resolved this issue. It have to reset device which is having android v. 6. Where on android 5, above steps worked.